# what is the URL I should use to edit a user account?

Tags: services

I need to edit user account data via services module

I tried `endpoint/user, endpoint/user/UID, endpoint/user/UID/edit, endpoint/user/update, endpoint/user/edit`

with args like in `user_resources.inc`

It returns `404user not registered`

despite successfully loggedin

```
$cookie_session = $logged_user->session_name . '=' . $logged_user->sessid;

// User data
$user_data = array();
$user_data['uid'] = $logged_user->user->uid;
$user_data['data']['name'] = 'test4'; 

$data = json_encode($user_data);

// cURL code
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/html/mob/api-    mob/user/".$user_data['uid']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$cookie_session"); // use the previously saved session
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data), mymodule_get_csrf_header())                                                                       
);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

what I am missing here or if one could do it via services please provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *update a user* with Drupal [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services), you make a **PUT** call to:

```
?q=[my-endpoint]/user/1.json
```

Replacing `[my-endpoint]` with the machine name of your Service endpoint. Here's some example *JSON* to **PUT**:

```
{
  "uid":"1",
  "name":"bob",
  "mail":"bob@hotmail.com",
  "current_pass":"secret",
  "pass_pass1":"new-secret",
  "pass_pass2":"new-secret"
}
```

You *must* also attach a **header** to your call with a name of `X-CSRF-Token` using a value that can be retrieved here: `?q=services/session/token`

Comment: is there exist any other method than PUT as the server didn't accept PUT requests

Comment: No, `PUT` is the default HTTP method used by the Services module for updating entities. You'll have to build your own custom Service Resource  (which will use a POST method).